# Cannot login to Oracle Enterprise Manager Express

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager, oracle-enterprise-linux

I have downloaded Oracle Developer Days Database 12c virtualbox image. I can boot it and access the desktop. When I try to log in to Enterprise Manager (EM) Express using the URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/em I am asked to install Adobe Flash. I install it and get to the login screen.

If I try to login as SYSTEM I get the following error:

[image]

But when I try to log in as user SYS I get a strange error: Security token does not match. You must login again..

[image]

To me it looks like the credentials for SYS are OK, but there is something wrong with the user in the database. Is this correct and if so how can I fix it? Or is EM Express just not setup on the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This document from Oracles Metalink](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=185690872522025&id=1968763.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=16vhefh1mo_9) solves it. The solution contains 3 steps:

1. Make sure that XDB_WALLET is recreated successfully.
2. Make sure XDB is installed successfully and the appropriate roles, EM_EXPRESS_BASIC/ALL is applied.
3. Use IE 11.0.9600.16476 with compatibility view.

[Mark Stewart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100021/cannot-login-to-oracle-enterprise-manager-express/32128016#32128016) covers step 2.

The first two steps are not strictly necessary. It looks like they have already been applied to the image in my case. All I had to do was use a different browser. Opera, Chrome, and IE all worked, but Firefox didn't.

The fact that Oracle installs a browser that doesn't work with EM Express and that Adobe Flash is not installed when it's required is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a personal user ID, grant DBA to it, and try granting EM_EXPRESS_ALL role to your user ID.

Answer (score 1):

After making sure that a desired account has `EM_EXPRESS_ALL` granted I just accessed `Enterprise Manager` using New Private Window in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Edge, no problem accessing Oracle 12c EM
In Microsoft IE 11, no problem accessing Oracle 12c EM
In Firefox : Security Token does not match

Found a solution for Firefox on [Is there a way to make Firefox ignore invalid ssl-certificates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088/is-there-a-way-to-make-firefox-ignore-invalid-ssl-certificates)

Go to Tools > Options > Advanced "Tab"(?) > Encryption Tab

Click the "Validation" button, and uncheck the checkbox for checking validity

Be advised though that this is pretty unsecure as it leaves you wide open to accept any invalid certificate. I'd only do this if using the browser on an Intranet where the validity of the cert isn't a concern to you, or you aren't concerned in general.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this because of the cookie data stored by Adobe Flash. Browsing on Private mode or Incognito did not help. Here are the steps to remove the stored data and start using EM on Chrome:

1. Go to `Settings`>`Advanced`>`Content Settings`>`Cookies`
2. Coose `See all cookies and site data`
3. In the cookies search box, key in the hostname used to access EM. I run EM on my localhost and hence filtered by localhost:
   [image]
   You can see Flash data being listed
4. Click on the item to expand and delete the item related to EM:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The same error still exists in 2019 on EM with Chrome Version 76.0.3809.87. My solution is to add EM URL to the "Allow" section in the Cookies section.

Answer (score -1):

Use internet explorer to login to EM .
The other browser are not compatible with enterprise manager